# How to find resulting intensity in 3 beam interference?

Tags: optics, waves, interference

Suppose we have three incident  light beams coming from slits S¹, S², S³ with some initial phase differences $Φ¹²,Φ²³,Φ³¹$ between them interfering at a point and we want to calculate resulting intensity.

We proceed by writing resultant from beam 1 and beam 2 and then finding resultant of $I¹²$ and $I³$

Now I am unabale to figure out what to put the phase difference in the second case?

I think we can't put Φ¹³ because it was P.D. between 1 and 2 and not between resultant and 3. Same for the other also. I even don't know how to calculate P.D. between resultant and 3 because resultant beam is not coming from a single slit but its a net effect of 1 and 2.

To understand the question more clearly, see this.[image]

Here the P.D. between 1&2; and 2&3 can be easily found to be $2π/3$ and $2π$ respectively. Firstly, 2 and 3 give $I¹²=4I$ at $P$ and for calculating net Intensity we need phaase diff. between this $I¹²$ and $I$ (which is basically $I³$)

Comment: "Writing resultant" - what is a 'resultant'? "what to put the phase diference in the second case" - you didn't present multiple cases of anything, and also don't know what you mean by 'put' the phase difference. "P.D." - either define the acronym or write the full term down. "how to calculate P.D.  between resultant and 3" - I can't work out what you mean by this. What is '3'? What is 'resultant'? I don't know how you found phase differences to be $2\pi/3$ and $2 \pi$ when the distance between slits or between S and P have not been specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add sinusoidal functions very easily, by using something called Phasor Diagram.

Plot all the intensities on the phasor diagram by keeping the phase difference in mind.

$S_1P - S_2P = \frac{\lambda}{6} \implies \phi_{12} = \pi/3$

$S_1P - S_3P = \frac{2\lambda}{3} \implies \phi_{13} = 4\pi/3$

**Like this**: (*Taking the initial phase of S3 as reference*)

[image: Phasor Diagram]

After making the phasor diagram, calculate the resultant, treating them as vectors. In this case as rays coming from S2 and S3 are out of phase, they are simply being cancelled and the net intensity at P is due to S1 only and is equal to $I$.

However, if you still want to know what will be the phase difference between $I_{12}$ and ${I_3}$, then calculate the resultant of S1 and S2 on phasor diagram keeping S3 intact, and then find the angle between resultant and S3, like this:

[image]

[image]

Calculate $\theta$ and the phase difference will be given by $\frac{\pi}{2} + \theta$

Comment: I think phase diff. will be two times of S¹P -S²P and same for other.

Comment: X= λ/3 here i think for 1 and 2. You are taking it from S1 i think. BTW thanks for the method. Great help

Comment: S1P-S2P is just half the phase difference

Comment: Bhai ray S se aa rahi hai na? S1 se nahi